# Will those destroyed in Sodom/Gomorrah and in the Flood be resurrected according to Jehovahs Witnesses?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, resurrection

Jehovahs Witnesses teach that the majority of humans who ever lived will be resurrected and given a chance to choose to be obedient and loyal to Jehovah during the 1000 years judgment period.

Are there exceptions for those in biblical times that were killed in events orchestrated by God?

For example 185,000 Assyrians killed in a single night? The wicked who drowned in the flood? The inhabitants of Sodom and Gomorrah?

Will these be resurrected or are they considered permanently annihilated?

Comment: Has there been increased light?  At the 2023 annual meeting Geoff Jackson said "we don't know" who will or who won't be resurrected and "we don't need to know."

Comment: @Lesley yes a lot of adjustment to previous dogmatic beliefs were made in that AM.   Yiu are on the right track.  The video is available in the website jw.org

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion to go to the official J.W. link but I detest videos! Give me the written word any day of the week.

Comment: @Lesley it will no doubt be coming in written form.

Comment: No you can fast forward to about 18:00 into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150855/discussion-between-lesley-and-user-14).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a selection of some quotes from older Watchtower magazines showing what they used to think would happen to Old Testament people who were destroyed because of their wickedness:

> **[Watchtower 2022 September p.16](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2022567#h=14):**  The third group comprises the goats, who will be destroyed at Armageddon. Their names are not in the book of life. Jesus says that they "will depart into everlasting cutting-off."... The same could be said of those who, down through time, have deliberately sinned against the holy spirit. They too receive everlasting destruction, not everlasting life. Clearly, they will not be resurrected.

> **[Watchtower 2006 March 15 p.6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2006201?#h=14):** Some committed sins for which there is no forgiveness. They are not in Hades (mankind's common grave) but in Gehenna, a symbolic place of eternal destruction.

> **[Watchtower 2006 June 15 p.6](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2006441?#h=15):** There is going to be a resurrection of both the righteous and the unrighteous.  So even "the unrighteous," many individuals who did not know and serve Jehovah, will get a future opportunity to gain God's favor.

> **[Watchtower 2005 July 15 p.16](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2005528?#h=4):** Those who are judged unworthy of a resurrection are pitched into “Gehenna,” or “the lake of fire.” (Matthew 5:22; Mark 9:47, 48; Revelation 20:14) Among these would be the first human pair, Adam and Eve, the betrayer Judas Iscariot, and certain ones who died when God executed judgment upon them, such as the people in Noah’s day and the inhabitants of Sodom and Gomorrah."

**Recently this judgmental view has been modified.**  At the 2023 Annual Meeting a talk was given about trusting Jehovah, the merciful judge.  [Governing Body member David Splane](https://www.jw.org/en/library/videos/#en/mediaitems/StudioFeatured/pub-jwb-108_8_VIDEO) (18:00) said that the Bible tells us that the wicked men of Nineveh would rise up again because they repented.  He said “we shouldn’t be dogmatic”.  The current view is that they don’t know who will and who will not be resurrected, and we don’t need to know.

**The answer to your question** is that the Governing Body is no longer being dogmatic about those who died in the flood, or at the destruction of Sodom & Gomorrah, or the people of Nineveh.  The message is to leave the judging to Jehovah and to Jesus.

Comment: Can you link to the video and approximate time stamp?

Comment: Every week I have a lap-top housekeeping routine where I delete all the links I've been using to clean out the historical data.  I regret that jw.org video link has gone.  However, if anyone wants to look at it, they just need to search for the 2023 Annual Meeting (part 2) at about 16 minutes in. The people who died in the flood, the men of Nineveh who repented, the inhabitants of Sodom & Gomorrah, and the Assyrian soldiers are all mentioned. At about 37 minutes in it says the judging of the "sheep and the goats" doesn't happen till the end of the great tribulation,just prior to Armageddon.

Comment: @Lesley I added links to the Watchtower articles you cited and added a link to the Annual Meeting with the approximate timestamp.